# Drupal custom content type list view

Tags: drupal, drupal-nodes, drupal-content-types

I have created custom content types and nodes for each.

What's the best way to create a page that shows a list of recent nodes of just a specific content type?  I was planning on using the Views module.  Should I create a custom `node--type.tpl.php` file and add a custom block for the View list to display into?  Most importantly, how do I link to this custom page (and **not** to a specific node item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant you just use date or time published in sort criteria, and use node type for filter?

Comment: How do I set the filter in the URL?  Would I do it as a $_GET on node (so site.com/node/?content=type)?

Comment: what version drupal you using. under basic settings set, style to unformatted, row style to node. Set sort criteria to Node: Post date so it displays newest. add filter Node: Type and select your content typle. On the left add a page display then under page settings you specify the path/url. That should be it

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.   Where would I go to set these settings?  Views?

Comment: Enable the Views module and the Views UI module. Create a view at /admin/structure/views/add then the settings described above will be on the following page.